# DynamoDB exceeding provisioned throughput during import

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

While doing an import of data (first ingest after creating the table), throughput maxes out during import.

Is there a way to seed your DynamoDB database with database where it is not subject to the regular write throughput settings?

Or, are we expected set a very high provisioned write throughput capacity for a few minutes during the data import process?

I'm not sure what the convention is here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the BatchWriteItem API to do the initial load? That can be enough sometimes.

Otherwise, the unfortunate answer is that you need to temporarily increase the write throughout. The SDKs also have built in retry logic, so you could tune that as well to ensure everything is written.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option - for seeding just temporarily increase your write throughput if you need it to go faster (does speed *really* matter, or can you live with this being slower?).  Also, I'd recommend increasing the maximum number of retries on the retry strategy in the DDB ClientConfiguration.

Be careful with the "very high" throughput option, as this can cause repartitioning on the AWS side, and can cause throughput dilution on your table when you reduce it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

All read and write requests are subject to the provisioned write throughput.  Increase the provisioned write throughput while importing your data and decrease it afterwards.